# Azure App-Service alerts on auto-scaled instance count with condition

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-alerts

Context : app-service in Azure with enabled auto-scale 2 to 8 instances. Usually workload fluctuates between 2..4 instances, and only on rare occasions scaling maxes out to 8 instances - for such cases I want to set up an alert. Let's say, I am interested in all scaling operation above 4 instance count.

Problem : cannot find an alert "scope + condition signal" combination where instance count of auto-scale would be possible to select. Does such data is accessible at all?

And "no" - I do not want to use OOB "Scale out - Notify" functionality, because this feature sends out emails about all scaling operations. Since I am not interested 2..4 instances and only >4 instances, conditioning must be possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create the alert mechanism for the autoscale operation in web app by projecting the autoscale operation logs to log analytic workspace & followed by creating custom alert.

Here are the steps you need to follow:

1. Go to Scale-out (App service plan) option in the portal under that Navigate to Diagnostic settings.

[image]

2. Create Diagnostic settings for the autoscale operations & project those logs to log analytics workspace.

[image]

3. Based on the requirement shared above, use the below query to pull scale out operation of a web app  with instance count  is greater.

```html
AutoscaleScaleActionsLog | where OperationName == 'InstanceScaleAction' and ResultType  == "Succeeded" 
    | where  NewInstanceCount >4 and ScaleDirection  == 'Increase'
```

4. Use the New alert rule option in the log analytics space to create a custom alert & using the above query as signal as shown in below picture.

[image]

Here is the sample image of the alert rule that was created using the above query

[image]

The above alert query run for every thirty minutes , if there any autoscale operation got recorded it will trigger an email to mentioned recipients.

5. click on save , enable the alert rule

Here is the sample email output triggered by alert rule

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.